# What is "p?p->next:0" in this C snippet and how do I run it?

Tags: c

I want to check how this p?p->next:0 works.
Its not the same operator as in java? Replacement, one liner for "if"?

e.g.

```
x = (5>6)? 10 : 4 ; //should assign x =4


struct node 
{
int value;
struct node *next;
};
void rearrange(struct node *list)
{
struct node *p, * q;
int temp;
if ((!list) || !list->next) 
    return;
p = list;
q = list->next;
while(q) 
{
    temp = p->value;
    p->value = q->value;
    q->value = temp;
    p = q->next;
    q = p?p->next:0;
}
}
```

//int main

Comment: Yes it is. ..``

Comment: ternary operator is the same as in java; `p->next` is a pointer here as opposed to java's lambda

Comment: could u explain how the last line works? I m confused abut p?p->next:0 ; what is assigned and why is there ":0"?

Comment: It's explained in the duplicate that is linked.

Comment: if p->next is null  - true , q = p , else q = 0?

Comment: no, if p is true, assign `p->next` to q, otherwise assign 0 to q.. but since p is not a boolean, I don't remember how it worked in C.. perhaps it checks null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C, 0 is `false`, everything else is `true`.  The ternary operator used here is shorthand for

```
if (p)
{
  q = p->next;
}
else
{
  q = 0;
}
```

where `if(p)` is true for any value of `p != 0`.  My preference when dealing with pointers is to compare against`NULL` instead of 0, `if (p != NULL){ ... }`, but it's not uncommon to see 0 used.  On every system I've worked on, `NULL` is 0, but I don't *think* that's mandated in the standard..?  Someone here will know.

Comment: `p` is a pointer, not an integer

Comment: @paddy correct. There's plenty of `c` code that checks pointers this way.

Comment: `NULL` is required to be a null pointer constant.  Literal `0` is also a null pointer constant.  They are not necessarily identical (`NULL` might expand to `(void *)0`, for example), but they can be used interchangeably as null pointers, and they compare equal to each other and to all other null pointers.

Comment: @JohnBollinger thanks for the info/clarification.

Comment: @usr2564301 even though you won't be notified... fair enough. Better complain to SO, looks like all their language tags have been code-ticked.

Comment: @yano: post editors *do* get notified :) Code ticking things that are clearly `not` code is an annoying habit, `and` personally, I edit it out whenever I see it. There are a *lot* of broken posts on SO – alas, it appears not everyone is interested in maintaining a reasonably high level of quality.

Comment: @usr2564301 ahhh, your name didn't autocomplete when I started typing it, so I didn't think you'd get notified. I guess I get a certain satisfaction when the language name I type matches what the code tag looks like, but you're right it's not code, I'll try to remember to stop doing it.

Answer (score 1):

NULL pointer is nothing but `(void*) 0`, so `q = p?p->next:0;` expands to

```
if (p != NULL)
    q = p->next;
else
    q = NULL;
```